# Syntax Error Error When Trying to Start GraphQL Yoga Server

Tags: javascript, graphql, prisma, prisma-graphql

I'm trying to run my GraphQL Yoga server but it's complaining about a syntax error in my `db.js` file:

> GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Cannot parse the unexpected character ".".

[image]

```
const { Prisma } = require("prisma-binding");

const db = new Prisma({
  typeDefs: './generated/prisma-client/prisma-schema.js',
  endpoint: process.env.PRISMA_ENDPOINT,
  secret: process.env.PRISMA_SECRET,
  debug: false
});

module.exports = db;
```

The line it doesn't like is `typeDefs`. When I remove the dot and just say `"generated/prisma-client/prisma-schema.js"` it can't parse the unexpected character "generated".

Any ideas what's going on?

Thanks

Comment: That looks like a syntax error being thrown while parsing your schema. Specifically, you've got a period somewhere that doesn't belong. If possible, update your question to include your type definitions.

Comment: Have you tried renaming the file end with `.graphql` instead of `.js`? I think it will try to parse your typedefs as string rather than a file if you don't.

Comment: I think @braza probably [hit the nail on the head](https://github.com/prisma/prisma-binding#constructoroptions-prismaoptions-prisma). If it's expecting the file to be a GraphQL document and you're giving it a js file, it'll error out because a js file is not a valid GraphQL document

Answer (score 0):

`prisma generate` creates a folder with the following structure

[image]

Inside of `prisma-schema.js` it exports a `typeDefs` property which is all graphql 
so in `db.js` you can import it like this

`const typeDefs = require("./generated/prisma-client/prisma-schema").typeDefs`